# Objective-c SMS recipients empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, sms

I have set up the composer so the body of message is populated already but left the recipient empty so it can be populated manually.

The API has no delegate method that I can find that allows me to be notified of the changes to the recipients array.

The delegate method:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;
```

Is the only method called after message is sent but the recipients array is empty.

Can anyone tell me another way to access this property?

```
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message"];
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    //[messageController setRecipients:recipients];// This set to nil so the textfield can be filled manually and this the problem
    [messageController setBody:message];

    // Present message view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can initialize the MessageComposer contents and present, but unfortunately we can't get the changes to the recipients array or access any values after presenting the controller. -- No getter methods available.

But you can check whether the message is sent to correct recipient and with correct body by the code below:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
 NSLog(@"Message: %@", controller.body);

 NSLog(@"Recipients:");
 for (NSString *recipient in controller.recipients) {
  NSLog(recipient);
 }
 switch (result) {
  case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
   NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
   break;
  case MessageComposeResultSent:
   NSLog(@"Result: sent");
   // Check that the correct message has been sent
   if([controller.body isEqualToString:correctMessage]) {
    BOOL correctRecipient = NO;
    for (NSString *recipient in controller.recipients) {
     if([recipient isEqualToString:correctRecipient]) {
      correctRecipient = YES;
     }
    }

    if(correctRecipient) {
     NSLog(@"Correct message sent to correct recipient!");
    } else {
     NSLog(@"Message or recipient was wrong");
    }
   }

   break;
  case MessageComposeResultFailed:
   NSLog(@"Result: failed");
   break;
  default:
   NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
   break;
 }

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing in the delegate method but the controller.recipient array is always nil. the body is a static message so it really doesn't matter. I assumed the private api would add the manually entered numbers into the recipients array but it seems that it doesn't.